# How to detect iPad using django-mobile

Tags: django

I just gave [django-moble](https://github.com/gregmuellegger/django-mobile) a try.

I really like the concept and helps my project to detect mobile device.
However, I am trying to find when the request is made by iPad browser.
I have added the following to the Settings.py
FLAVOURS = ('full', 'mobile','ipad')

But it is not working.
Can anybody kindly gave me how I can proceed from here?
What else do I need to do?

The following is my view.

```
if get_flavour()=='full':
  t = loader.get_template('index.html')
elif get_flavour()=='ipad':
  t = loader.get_template('ipad.html')
else:
  t = loader.get_template('mobile.html')
```

Thank you for your time in advance.

Comment: What does `print get_flavour()` give you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Out of the box, Django-mobile only provides two flavours. From the [github page](https://github.com/gregmuellegger/django-mobile):

> Note: By default django-mobile only distinguishes between full and mobile flavour.

In order to actually detect iPad vs any other device, you will need to replace the existing `MobileDetectionMiddleware` with `MyMobileDetectionMiddleware` in `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` in your `settings.py`. You can use the existing [`MobileDetectionMiddleware` class](https://github.com/gregmuellegger/django-mobile/blob/master/django_mobile/middleware.py#L21) as a guide, and there is some information on customization [on the same github page](https://github.com/gregmuellegger/django-mobile#mobiledetectionmiddleware)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a quick and easy fix to include an ipad as a 'mobile' flavor, then you can modify the [middleware class](https://github.com/gregmuellegger/django-mobile/blob/master/django_mobile/middleware.py) by commenting out (or removing) the user_agents_exception_search on line [42](https://github.com/gregmuellegger/django-mobile/blob/master/django_mobile/middleware.py#L42). Also comment out self.user_agents_exception_search_regex at line [51](https://github.com/gregmuellegger/django-mobile/blob/master/django_mobile/middleware.py#L51). Then on line [60](https://github.com/gregmuellegger/django-mobile/blob/master/django_mobile/middleware.py#L60), remove the 'and not' from the 'if statement'.

Here's a simple modified code for the lazy:

```
import re
from django_mobile import flavour_storage
from django_mobile import set_flavour, _init_flavour
from django_mobile.conf import settings


class SetFlavourMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        _init_flavour(request)

        if settings.FLAVOURS_GET_PARAMETER in request.GET:
            flavour = request.GET[settings.FLAVOURS_GET_PARAMETER]
            if flavour in settings.FLAVOURS:
                set_flavour(flavour, request, permanent=True)

    def process_response(self, request, response):
        flavour_storage.save(request, response)
        return response


class MobileDetectionMiddleware(object):
    user_agents_test_match = (
        "w3c ", "acs-", "alav", "alca", "amoi", "audi",
        "avan", "benq", "bird", "blac", "blaz", "brew",
        "cell", "cldc", "cmd-", "dang", "doco", "eric",
        "hipt", "inno", "ipaq", "java", "jigs", "kddi",
        "keji", "leno", "lg-c", "lg-d", "lg-g", "lge-",
        "maui", "maxo", "midp", "mits", "mmef", "mobi",
        "mot-", "moto", "mwbp", "nec-", "newt", "noki",
        "xda",  "palm", "pana", "pant", "phil", "play",
        "port", "prox", "qwap", "sage", "sams", "sany",
        "sch-", "sec-", "send", "seri", "sgh-", "shar",
        "sie-", "siem", "smal", "smar", "sony", "sph-",
        "symb", "t-mo", "teli", "tim-", "tosh", "tsm-",
        "upg1", "upsi", "vk-v", "voda", "wap-", "wapa",
        "wapi", "wapp", "wapr", "webc", "winw", "xda-",)
    user_agents_test_search = u"(?:%s)" % u'|'.join((
        'up.browser', 'up.link', 'mmp', 'symbian', 'smartphone', 'midp',
        'wap', 'phone', 'windows ce', 'pda', 'mobile', 'mini', 'palm',
        'netfront', 'opera mobi', 'ipad',
    ))
    #user_agents_exception_search = u"(?:%s)" % u'|'.join((
    #   'ipad',
    #))
    http_accept_regex = re.compile("application/vnd\.wap\.xhtml\+xml", re.IGNORECASE)

    def __init__(self):
        user_agents_test_match = r'^(?:%s)' % '|'.join(self.user_agents_test_match)
        self.user_agents_test_match_regex = re.compile(user_agents_test_match, re.IGNORECASE)
        self.user_agents_test_search_regex = re.compile(self.user_agents_test_search, re.IGNORECASE)
        #self.user_agents_exception_search_regex = re.compile(self.user_agents_exception_search, re.IGNORECASE)

    def process_request(self, request):
        is_mobile = False

        if request.META.has_key('HTTP_USER_AGENT'):
            user_agent = request.META['HTTP_USER_AGENT']

            # Test common mobile values.
            if self.user_agents_test_search_regex.search(user_agent):
                is_mobile = True
            else:
                # Nokia like test for WAP browsers.
                # http://www.developershome.com/wap/xhtmlmp/xhtml_mp_tutorial.asp?page=mimeTypesFileExtension

                if request.META.has_key('HTTP_ACCEPT'):
                    http_accept = request.META['HTTP_ACCEPT']
                    if self.http_accept_regex.search(http_accept):
                        is_mobile = True

            if not is_mobile:
                # Now we test the user_agent from a big list.
                if self.user_agents_test_match_regex.match(user_agent):
                    is_mobile = True

        if is_mobile:
            set_flavour(settings.DEFAULT_MOBILE_FLAVOUR, request)
        else:
            set_flavour(settings.FLAVOURS[0], request)
```